# Swipe actions always have delete

Tags: swift, tableview

Every time I try to add an action swipe to delete still appears.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {


    let closeAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Share", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("OK, marked as Closed")

        success(true)
    })

    closeAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [closeAction])


}
```

Answer (score 2):

fixed

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
```